# Error Saving Image to Photo Library iOS/Mac Catalyst App Swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos, uiimage, mac-catalyst

I have built an iOS app that saves the image from a UIImageView to the user's photo library.
This works on iOS but when I am trying to add support for Mac to this app using Apple's Mac Catalyst product in iOS 13/macOS Catalina, the image does not save and I am shown an error message.

The code I am using to save the photo is copied below:

```
@objc func export(sender:AnyObject) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.previewImageView.image!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}

@objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        print("Error saving: \(error)")
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved", message: "Your image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
}
```

The error message in the alert view is "Unknown Error" but here is the error message that is printed in the Xcode console:

```
[GatekeeperXPC] XPC connection error to assetsd getSystemLibraryURLReadOnlyServiceWithReply: : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.photos.service was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.photos.service was invalidated.}
```

---

```
Error saving: Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-1 "Unknown error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown error, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000cfe4f0 {Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-1 "Unknown error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown error, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000d01680 {Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-1 "Unknown error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown error, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000d03930 {Error Domain=com.apple.photos.error Code=41002 "Unable to obtain photolibraryd XPC proxy for getResourceWriteOnlyServiceWithReply:. photolibraryd could have crashed" UserInfo=0x6000017be600 (not displayed)}}}}}}
```

Do you know why this error is occurring and if there is anything I can do to get more information on how to fix this error or anything else I can try?

Thank you.

Comment: your app is using a lot of memory ?

Comment: I get the exact same error. Did you find a fix ? Thanks.

Comment: @stefat Please see answer copied below.

Comment: Do you find an answer? For my case I have one app that works and one didn't (and crashes just like yours), using the same routine as yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to save the images to MacOS through this Mac Catalyst App using the following code in Swift;

```
func insertImageMac(image : UIImage, albumName : String) {
    let collection = fetchAssetCollectionWithAlbumName(albumName: albumName)
    if collection == nil {
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: albumName)
            }, completionHandler: {(success, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Error: " + error!.localizedDescription)
                }

                if success {
                    let newCollection = self.fetchAssetCollectionWithAlbumName(albumName: albumName)
                    self.insertImage(image: image, intoAssetCollection: newCollection!)
                }
            }
        )
    } else {
        self.insertImage(image: image, intoAssetCollection: collection!)
    }
}

func fetchAssetCollectionWithAlbumName(albumName : String) -> PHAssetCollection? {

    let fetchOption = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOption.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title == '" + albumName + "'")

    let fetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(
        with: PHAssetCollectionType.album,
        subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype.albumRegular,
        options: fetchOption)
    let collection = fetchResult.firstObject as? PHAssetCollection

    return collection
}

func insertImage(image : UIImage, intoAssetCollection collection : PHAssetCollection) {
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
        let request = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: collection)
            if request != nil && creationRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset != nil {
                request!.addAssets([creationRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset!] as NSFastEnumeration)
            }

        },

        completionHandler: { (success, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error: " + error!.localizedDescription)
                let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error!.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default))
                self.present(ac, animated: true)
            } else {
                let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save success", message: "Image saved", preferredStyle: .alert)
                ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default))
                self.present(ac, animated: true)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

...and calling it inside my button function with the image;

```
insertImageMac(image: myImage, albumName: "AlbumName")
```

Comment: I tried @Tom's code.  No Joy.  I give a known good UIImage and get a success alert, but no picture appears in the Photo Album specified. Oddly, if I look at the Albums's estimated count, it increases by one each time I try a save. Are the images invisible or broken in saving?